# How to locally test a pull request from GitLab?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, pull-request

In order to review/test a GitLab pull request, one could use this command:

```
git fetch remote pull/ID/head:branch_to_use_locally
```

Here, `remote` is a project on GitLab. [More details in GitLab FAQ](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).

What is the corresponding command when one uses GitLab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite similar. The little differences exist because in **GitLab** `merge requests` are used instead of `pull requests` from **GitHub**. This consists in creating a branch away from `master` and merging into it later.

To test a *Merge Request* all you need to do is to fetch and checkout the branch sent for merge:

```
git fetch <repo> <branch>
git checkout -b <branch>
```

Also there is a button in every merge request with the instructions to checkout the diffs locally:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First pull merge request to a new branch

```
git fetch REMOTE merge-requests/MERGE_REQUEST_ID/head:BRANCH_NAME
```

Real example would be like: `git fetch origin merge-requests/1/head:add_some_feature`

Then check it out

```
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
```

In above example would be like: `git checkout add_some_feature`

Now check the new branch.

**Important point**: `BRANCH_NAME` is the source branch of merge request. It's not the target branch.

Comment: If anyone's curious, [this is documented in the docs on merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/index.html#checkout-merge-requests-locally).